# To build an examination pattern static content

Tags: android

I  want to bulid an android application to conduct a  examination.  Suppose there are two subjects, and each contains 20 questions each. So how to implement / best way to implement  these questions and answers?  I want to reuse the Activity and is the way of using Strings.xml is preferred? how? All the things are Static content, all at client side only.
  Thanx in advance.

--meher.

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 arrays (questions and answers) inside your arrays.xml. Example is here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/arrays.html
If you want to reuse existing activity, then your application will be a sequence of different objects of the same activity (lets call it QuestionActivity), and you can call new one when user press Next. In this way you should put the number of question to display inside intent, so the activity will know what to display.
User can press Back button and his answers can be lost. So also you should memorize answers to questions when user chooses some answer.